# Active Record find by ids

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can I compose a query to find records by the ids I'm passing?
Currently I query them with this command `Model.where(id: [1,2,3])`. Everything works fine, but  this is not the behavior I want. The case is that if there is no record with id=3 it will return results for id=1 or 2 and I need to return the results only when all ids are found or return nothing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this will be one of the ways

```
ids = [1,2,3]
records = Model.where(id: ids) 

result = records.count == ids.count ? records : []
```

Answer (score 1):

```
User.find([1,3,4]).count
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 3, 4)
=> 3

User.find([1,2,4]).count
  User Load (0.8ms)  SELECT `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` IN (1, 2, 4)
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find all Users with IDs (1, 2, 4) (found 2 results, but was looking for 3)
```

Comment: Sorry, but `find` will not help, because I need to chain my `where` statements.